# C# The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn programming and I am starting with a book called Software Development Fundamentals. However I am having loads of difficulty understanding certain subjects. Especially because my native language is not English. I am stuck at the subject (events) and (delegates). I feel like this is to difficult for me, I can not even get this code to work!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Lesson02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Changed += new EventHandler(r_Changed);
            r.Length = 10;
        }
        static void r_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle r = (Rectangle)sender;
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Value Changed: Length = {0}",
                r.Length);
        }

    }
    class Rectangle
    {
        public EventHandler Changed;
        private double length;
        public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            return length;
        }
        set
        {
            length = value;
            Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }



}


}
```

I get this error:

> Error  1   The name 'r_Changed' does not exist in the current context  14  59  Lesson02

Comment: C# is case sensitive. Check the spelling of `r_Changed` vs `r_changed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C# is case-sensitive language**. You have defined function as `r_changed` and using it as `r_Changed`

Use

```
r.Changed += new EventHandler(r_changed);
```

instead of

```
r.Changed += new EventHandler(r_Changed);
```

Comment: Thanks, the book "Wiley.Exam.98-361.MTA.Software.Development.Fundamentals"
 clearly had it misspelled !

Comment: @user1442232 You should give this answer a checkmark. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you'd know by now that C# is a case sensitive programming language.

**This should work**

```
static void r_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle)sender;
    Console.WriteLine("Value Changed: Length = {0}", r.Length);
}
```

Notice how `r_Changed` is capitals (`r_changed` is what you originally defined)

I would suggest using this because it is easier to read.

Comment: Suggestions are often ok, however you should state 'why' if you make suggestions.

Comment: @Silvermind It's easier to read but still, the other suggestion was posted anyways. Methods should usually be capitalized after the first word (or letter) is lower case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little typo mistake in your code. It should be `r_Changed` instead of `r_changed` in the your Event Handler.

i.e write

```
static void r_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

in place of

```
static void r_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

(**Remember C# is Case-sensitive)**